# Retrieve Data From DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am running a SQL Query which will return a count the query is

```
Select Count(numstudents) from classA
```

I am using `C#` to connect to SQL Server and execute this query, but my issue is, how do I get the actual number returned?  My current method returns the number of rows in the `DataTable` which by default will always be 1.  I need to get the `Count()` returned.

Here is full `C#` syntax:

```
private void GetData()
{
  DataSet ds = new DataSet()
  using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("RunAStoredProc", con))
    {
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
  }
  DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
  table1 = ds.Tables[0];
  DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
  table2 = ds.Tables[1];

  string numberreturned = table1.Rows.Count.ToString();
  Console.WriteLine(numberreturned);
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Stored procedure reads like such:

```
Alter Procedure [dbo].[GetData]
As

Select Count(*) FROM classA

Select studentfirstname, studentlastname FROM classA  
Where enrolled = 'Yes'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an SqlDataAdapter and all the infrastructure required to work with if you just have a single value returned by your Stored Procedure. Just use ExecuteScalar

```
int count = 0;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("RunAStoredProc", con))
{
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
Console.WriteLine(count);
Console.ReadKey();
```

However if your really want to use an adapter and a dataset then you can find the result of your query reading the value from the first row and first column from the returned table

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(table1.Rows[0][0]);
```

or even (without declaring the table1 variable)

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
```

To discover the difference between the result of the first select statement and the count of rows returned in the second select statement you could write

```
int allStudents = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
int enrolledStudents = ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count;

int notEnrolledStudents = allStudents - enrolledStudents;
```

Comment: I am actually returning two select statements (why I am using the SqlDataAdapter) - I need the count from the first select (can't get syntax correct) and I iterate the data in ds.Tables[1];

Comment: Can you add the code of your stored procedure? If this is a count query then there is just one row in the first or second table of the dataset. In that case the second example should be enough to get back the count of students of classA (if this is stored in the first table)

Comment: Then the second example (the one that takes the first row, first column) of table1 should work and give you back the number of students in your classA table

Comment: By the way you don't need to create the two tables (_new DataTable()_) they already exists in the DataSet and thus your new is just wasting time and memory

Comment: see edited 2nd query, copy/paste malfunciton - the where clause prevents the two numbers from being the same.  Basically I am looking at people who have pre-registered against people who have acutally enrolled.

Comment: The second query doesn't return a count, it returns a number of record (rows) with student first and last name. In that case the Rows.Count could be used as your counter.

Comment: Correct, I am wanting to compare the number from the 1st count to the number returned from the Select Query.  I then write to the window first and last name of the students whom are enrolled.  But I am wanting to get the difference between the 1st query and the 2nd query.